# Java EOFException on reading a file

Tags: java, io, stream, datainputstream

I am reading a file in Java using this code

```
import java.io.*;

public class IOReadDataStreams {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        DataInputStream in = null;

        try{
            in =  new DataInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("invoicedata")));
            int unit;
            double price;
            String desc;
            while(true){
                unit = in.readInt();
                price = in.readDouble();
                desc = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println(unit+" " + price +" "+ desc);
            }
        }catch(EOFException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(in != null)
                in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The file that I was trying to read was made by this Piece of code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;


public class IODataStreams {
    static final  String  dataFile = "invoicedata";
    static final double[] prices = new double[]{19.99, 9.99,15.99,3.99,4.99};
    static final int[] unitCount = new int[]{12,8,13,29,50};
    static final String[] desc = new String[]{
        "Java T Shirt",
        "C# T Shirt",
        "PHP T Shirt",
        "Ruby T Shirt",
        "Go! T Shirt"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        DataInputStream in = null;  
        try{
            out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("invoicedata")));
            for(int i = 0 ; i < prices.length; i++){
                out.writeUTF(desc[i]);
                out.writeInt(unitCount[i]);
                out.writeDouble(prices[i]);
            }
        }finally{
            if(out != null)
                out.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Now I am wondering why my first code (the one that reads the file) is not Printing the price,desc and the unit. it keeps on returning a EOFException

The error is specifically on this line

```
desc = in.readUTF();
```

Comment: Try specifying the full filesystem path to your `invoicedata` file.

Comment: They are in the same path. everything is working with regards to path.

Comment: Have you also tried making sure that you're reading the data in the same order that you wrote it?  The example code provided does not appear to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing data in this order:

```
            out.writeUTF(desc[i]);
            out.writeInt(unitCount[i]);
            out.writeDouble(prices[i]);
```

But reading data in the wrong order:

```
            unit = in.readInt();
            price = in.readDouble();
            desc = in.readUTF();
```

You need to read and write the data in the same order, specifically the `UTF` bit, because that doesn't translate into a number.

When I switched these lines so that the read and write was in the same order, this is what `IOReadDataStreams` outputed:

```
12 19.99 Java T Shirt
8 9.99 C# T Shirt
13 15.99 PHP T Shirt
29 3.99 Ruby T Shirt
50 4.99 Go! T Shirt
```

Before reaching the EOF of the file and throwing (like it should) an EOFException.

Comment: Nevermind it finally worked. So I need to read the data the same order as I wrote it?

Comment: @user962206 I tried running your code and put the data in the same order, I was able to read all of the data. You still get the exception because you're reading until the EOF (which is fine).